# Batch move files from multiple folders to single destination

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to write a script to help with my research.  I need to be able to move files from multiple subdirectories to a single destination directory.  I have a list of files to be moved, but have no experience writing anything like this.  Did some digging around and botched together this

```
@echo OFF

CHCP 65001 >NUL

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I In ("F:\Coyote Pics\Final sorted pictures\COYCAM1.txt") DO (
    xcopy /s "F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\%%I" "F:\Coyote Pics\Final sorted pictures\%%I*"
)

PAUSE
```

which depends on making a txt file of the file paths to be copied.  However, when I run the script, I get "file not found".  Not sure if this is the best way to do this or if there is an easier way.

For reference, here is an example of a list of files that I need to copy into a single destination folder.

```
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\bd\bdb71a66-4a70-4f34-adcb-2a4792d7a736.jpg
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\22\22976f1a-b718-43ac-89b1-5db2815f1a38.jpg
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\01\013a0efe-12e0-40fd-9057-bec92ead8865.jpg
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\47\47543fc8-7ba8-4989-b5e1-1e57052b5fd4.jpg
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\08\08d84e39-7458-4e8e-88bd-b443b8e419f2.jpg
F:\camelot\Datasets\default\Media\8e\8e814897-2f6f-45d4-9be3-77d41c4fc836.jpg
```

Comment: The source text file should list filenames only (no paths). You can dink with this using cmd as well: type `for /? |more` at the prompt for documentation on playing with the “modifiers” for variables containing path names — but doing it that was is harder than simply generating a source list of filenames without paths. Finally, you can always stick `echo` in front of a command to see what commands are actually being attempted.

Comment: The `xcopy` command line should probably read `xcopy "%%I" "F:\Coyote Pics\Final sorted pictures\%%~nxI"`…